# Sequences that diverge, limit stuff

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a quadratic based sequence,
say its of the general form : $y = ax^2 + bx +c$

To put a concrete example the sequence : $a(n) = n^2 +5n +6$

> $\lim{a(n)}\to\infty$ **when** $n\to\infty$

I am trying to think of an Epsilon-N way to prove this.
I am not sure how to start to break down the quadratic, would one factor it in product form and manipulate that, or would one use some kind of Triangle Inequality on the quadratic.

Hope to get some clarification on this.

Comment: You won't actually have an $\varepsilon$ value, but factor out $n^2$ and look at $a(n)=n^2(1+\frac5n+\frac{6}{n^2})\geq n^2$.

Comment: Hi Clayton, so I see that when you factored out that way, one factor being the squared term the other factor would tend to --> 1 as n--> infinity. that is clever. But hence can we just do an Epsilon-N proof (I know that there is no epsilon, i just call it that) on the quadratic part n^2.

Comment: So we choose some N, such that n >N,  a(n) > M [for any (large, positive) number M] so therefore N^2 > M, therefore N > root(M). Is this sufficient to do this just for treating this : a(n) as a(n) == n^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We notice that for positive $n$ we have $$a(n)> n^2$$Now for each $M$ we can choose $N=\max\{|M|,1\}$ and thus for $n>N$ we get $$a(n)>n^2\ge N^2\ge |M|^2\ge |M|\ge M$$

Comment: Hi Holo, I think I understand, based on your analysis and Clayton. Via the factoring from Clayton, we are able to set up an inequality to use such as a(n) >n^2. And if we want a(n) > M, for each n > N. which means for each choice of n, we always want that a(n) > M.

Comment: Yes, basically we notice that $a(n)>b(n)$ and then show that for all $M$ we have a point such that after that point we have $b(n)>M$ for all $n$, that implies $a(n)>M$. to remind you the definition of limit  diverge to infinity: $$\forall M\exists N\forall n\quad n>N\implies a(n)>M$$(note that this definition sometimes being called $M-N$ definition as analogy to the $\varepsilon-\delta$ and $\varepsilon-N$ definitions)

Comment: Hi Holo, thanks for the recap of the different definitions of these precise limit definitions, that is really helpful in general. I will award your answer as THE answer to this question. Regards, Palu